# Dynamically create webpages with different URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Wasn't able to find this.. maybe I wasn't looking correctly. But pretty much this is my view:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    @foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        <ul>
            <li>@dr["Name"].ToString() - @dr["Distance"].ToString()</li>
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

I want to create a new page (using c# and MVC) for each of the bullet points with different URL's depending on the name. How can I do that? Do I use ActionLink? Does it have to do with Routing?

Basically let's say you have a list of Restaurants, I want it so that when you click on a restaurant it takes you to a different URL like `yourdomain.com/restaurant-name`, and then I want to populate that page with some HTML. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: You really should not be consuming DataSets and DataTables from a view.  Create a Model and fill it with the proper data.  Look into Entity Framework (ORM that makes database to model mapping a breeze).

Answer (score 1):

The default route takes urls in the format:  domain.com/controller/action/id

So if you code up a Controller called `RestaurantsController` with an Action `View` then you can pass it the id of the restaurant you want to view... thusly:

*Yes, this is VB, I'm sure you can translate*

```
Public Function View(Optional ByVal id As String) As ActionResult

    '  Fetch your restaurant data...
    Dim model As Restaurant = RestaurantRepository.GetRestaurantById(id)

    Return View(model)

End Function
```

access the action via:   domain.com/Restaurants/View/whatever-your-restaurant-id-is

Then to make links for it in your razor view you can do:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link text here", "View", "Restaurants", 
                 htmlAttributes:=Nothing, routeValues:= New With {.id = dr["Name"]})
```

Comment: sorry to be a noob and thanks for the help! But anyway you could convert that into c#?

Comment: @vbaid: nope.  I'll leave that for you to do.

Comment: Actually, I just have one more question if that's okay @Sam Axe, I followed this and converted it. I then also made a ShowMenu.cshtml view, but when I run the program it gives me an error such as "the view or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations"

Comment: I think I forgot the link text parameter earlier.

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    @foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(@dr["Name"].ToString() + "-" + @dr["Distance"].ToString(), "ShowMenu", routeValues: new {id = dr["Name"] })</li>
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowMenu(string id)
        {
            return View(id);
        }
```